# R glm.fit does not return probability?

Tags: r, glm, lm, predict

First post here, newbie in R. So bear with me if I am not getting this post right :).

I am trying to use glm() to fit a model, and use predict on the model afterwards.

```
  fit_GLM <- glm(y ~., data = traintemp, family = "binomial")
  pred_GLM <- predict(fit_GLM, newdata = testtemp)
```

My training data consists of about 430000 observations, with 6 predictors and a binary outcome. I tried changing outcome with 0-1 or False-True.

My test data consists of about 215000 observations.

I can succesfully run the model, but the data returned by the predict function is a little bit weird. (for me) I am expecting a probability, but the function returns:

```
         Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
    -0.0433000 -0.0006504  0.0004760  0.0103800  0.0024810  1.0020000
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Also, if I run lm() instead, the results are very similar, but it runs soooo much faster, whats up with that?

Edit: example of my data:

```
TripType VisitNumber Weekday         Upc ScanCount DepartmentDescription FinelineNumber
1        0           7  Friday 60538815980         1                 SHOES           8931
2        0           7  Friday  7410811099         1         PERSONAL CARE           4504
3        0           8  Friday  2006613744         2 PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           1017
4        0           8  Friday  2006618783         2 PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           1017
5        0           8  Friday  7004802737         1 PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           2802
6        0           8  Friday  2238495318         1 PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           4501
```

Thank you and happy thanksgiving!

Edit 23 Train:

```
TripType Weekday         Upc ScanCount    DepartmentDescription FinelineNumber
1         0  Friday 60538815980         1                    SHOES           8931
2         0  Friday  7410811099         1            PERSONAL CARE           4504
3         0  Friday  2006613744         2    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           1017
4         0  Friday  2006618783         2    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           1017
5         0  Friday  7004802737         1    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           2802
6         0  Friday  2238495318         1    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           4501
7         0  Friday  5200010239         1              DSD GROCERY           4606
8         0  Friday 88679300501         2    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           3504
9         0  Friday  2238400200         2    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           3565
10        0  Friday 72450408840         1    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           1028
11        0  Friday 25541500000         2                    DAIRY           1305
12        0  Friday 72450403700         2    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           1018
13        0  Friday  7874204967         1 HOUSEHOLD CHEMICALS/SUPP            707
14        0  Friday  3270011053         3        PETS AND SUPPLIES           1001
15        0  Friday  1070080727         1      IMPULSE MERCHANDISE            115
16        0  Friday        3107         1                  PRODUCE            103
17        0  Friday        4011         1                  PRODUCE           5501
18        0  Friday  6414410235         1              DSD GROCERY           2008
19        0  Friday  4178900743         1        GROCERY DRY GOODS           3114
20        0  Friday  7800002374         1              DSD GROCERY           3467
```

Test:

```
   TripType Weekday         Upc ScanCount    DepartmentDescription FinelineNumber
1         0  Friday 68113152929        -1       FINANCIAL SERVICES           1000
2         0  Friday  2238403510         2    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           3565
3         0  Friday  2006613743         1    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           1017
4         0  Friday  2238400200        -1    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           3565
5         0  Friday 22006000000         1    MEAT - FRESH & FROZEN           6009
6         0  Friday  2236760452         1    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES              7
7         0  Friday 88679300501        -1    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           3504
8         0  Friday  3019294203         1    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           2801
9         0  Friday  2310010776         1        PETS AND SUPPLIES           3300
10        0  Friday  5114139038         1    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           4415
11        0  Friday  5114197561         1    PAINT AND ACCESSORIES           4415
12        0  Friday  2800053970         1  CANDY, TOBACCO, COOKIES            115
13        0  Friday  7794800902         1              DSD GROCERY           7950
14        0  Friday  7920018317         1      IMPULSE MERCHANDISE            110
15        0  Friday  3500076633         1            PERSONAL CARE            203
16        0  Friday  5460010568         1 HOUSEHOLD CHEMICALS/SUPP             52
17        0  Friday  2899521479         1       FABRICS AND CRAFTS           1059
18        0  Friday  2899521979         1       FABRICS AND CRAFTS           1062
19        0  Friday  1200004300         1              DSD GROCERY           9501
20        0  Friday 88743955560         1                MENS WEAR            144
```

Comment: Can you give us a small part of your 2 data sets using `dput` and `head` ? Something representative which may allow us to have the same problem you have.

Comment: Hi Etienne, I edited my post, will that work?

Comment: For the example of your data it is much easier for us if you use `dput(head(traintemp,20))` and `dput(head(testtemp,20))` as we can quickly paste it into R and use it.

Comment: Also, if will be best if `y` in both dataset have 0 and 1 to return the `glm`. Try to select some part of your data with that.

Comment: Hi again and thank you so much for helping me. I am trying to output the dput code, but it is way way to big to copy paste. Also, adding the response does not change my results (I also thought response was default?)

Comment: I also have to say that I removed one of the variables, looking at it made me realize it was not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?predict.glm`:

*the type of prediction required. The default is on the scale of the linear predictors; the alternative "response" is on the scale of the response variable. Thus for a default binomial model the default predictions are of log-odds (probabilities on logit scale) and **type = "response" gives the predicted probabilities**. The "terms" option returns a matrix giving the fitted values of each term in the model formula on the linear predictor scale.*

So in your case:

```
pred_GLM <- predict(fit_GLM, newdata = testtemp, type = "response")
```